# Save and retrieve states with redux-persist - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I'm new to react-native and I'm trying for the first time to save the states of my app.

In order to achieve this I've been suggested to use [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/blob/master/docs/recipes.md). 
I expected to find more examples and topics about it in the web and I feel that my idea about how redux-persist works is not that limpid.

I've followed the short guide in the github page but once I close and re-open my app I can't see saved states values but I see the default, initial states values.

This is my app.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, autoRehydrate } from 'redux-persist';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from './reducers';
import Router from './Router';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const store = compose(applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk), autoRehydrate())(createStore)(reducers); 
    persistStore(store, {storage: AsyncStorage}, () => {
        console.log('restored');
    })
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Do I need something else?**

**I'd also like to know how I can `console.log` all the states values inside the redux-persistor storage.**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you handling the `persist/REHYDRATE` action in your reducer? Doing so will also give you a convenient place to put a `console.log` statement so that you can see what is being persisted. See also: https://medium.com/@clrksanford/persist-ence-is-key-using-redux-persist-to-store-your-state-in-localstorage-ac6a000aee63

Answer (score 4):

You have put `persistStore` into `render` method.
Persistence call is a side-effect, that should never happen within `render`.

Move it to `componentWillMount`, as redux-persist documentation says to you

```
export default class AppProvider extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = { rehydrated: false }
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    persistStore(store, {}, () => {
      this.setState({ rehydrated: true })
    })
  }

  render() {
    if(!this.state.rehydrated){
      return <div>Loading...</div>
    }
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
         {() => <App />}
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

You need to defer initialization before store will be rendered. This is what this code snippet does

Answer (score 1):

@just-boris's answer may or may not solve this for you, but regardless you should definitely move the call to `persistStore` out of the `render` function for exactly the reasons they mention.

---

It's hard to tell what's going wrong when there aren't any errors, but I suspect that handling the `persist/REHYDRATE` action in one of your reducers will help you find the problem.

```
case 'persist/REHYDRATE': {
  console.log(action.payload) // persist's action uses "payload" not "data"

  return state // NOP, just wanted to log the payload
}
```

You can also use your browser's inspector tool to inspect local storage, which will give you an idea of what is being stored inside `redux-persist`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use

```
store.getState().whatEver;
```

Comment: React-persist doesn't actually add a key to your redux store, so you can't inspect it by looking at the state.